# IIS Rewrite Removing H from HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I'm getting an issue with IIS Url Rewriting. After the first rule all seems well, but then the url being passed into the second rule doesn't have the 'h' on the schema. I've got a trace and the url that comes in is:

product/car.aspx

This then passes through the first rule below  as:

https://fo.bar.com/product/car.aspx

But then the next rule is being passed in the url:

ttps://fo.bar.com/product/car.aspx

Any thoughts on this would be great. Below are my rules from the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <clear />
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove incorrect first char from query string" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">   
            <match url="(.*)"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^\&amp;(.*)"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}?{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
        </rule>
        ..................
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems that all you want to do is redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS?

If so, you can simplify the rules to be:

```
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```